# How to get time using toDate() and not format()

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I want to get the time string from `moment()` but using `toDate()` function and not `format()` function

I am able to get the time using format function but it differ from the date and time returned from `toDate(`) function.

```
moment().utc().toDate()
```

returned `Mon Aug 05 2019 17:08:08` and

```
moment().utc().format('hh:mm a')
```

returned `11:40`

I want to get `11:40` by using `toDate()` function and not `format()` function.

Comment: and what's the purpose of sticking only with `.toDate()`?

Comment: I have to use same datetime inside mongo query and use the same datetime outside.

Comment: Why don't you convert the date when reading/writing to the mongo db ?

Comment: I can't change the format of inside the query. I only can do it for outside it.

Comment: `toDate()` is function that returns the **native javascript date** object (`Date`) and not format (`string`) - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/.